# Creating a stacked area graph in AppDynamics dashboard

Tags: appdynamics

Is it possible to create a stacked area graph in AppDynamics? I want to show the cumulative effects of API response and browser DOM ready to visualize where variance is originating.

I can put both of these on a single graph, but if I choose Area, they overlap. How do I get them to stack?

I'm on AppDynamics Version 4.3.1.2, build 47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the widget settings make sure you select the "Stack Areas or Columns" checkbox. This works in every version of AppD I've used including 4.3.0.2.